# How to show zoomed graph with minimum bars with defined bar size using MPAndroid chart?

Tags: java, android, graph, mpandroidchart

I have created one graph which shows strings at x axis and dollars at y axis. I am able to see the values on graph but my data is too much to show on graph.

Graph is scrollable so I want to show minimun number of values on bar like below graph.

[image]

But now I am getting too much bars in graph like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
public void setGraph() {

    if (sessionData.getString("graphType", "").equals("d") || sessionData.getString("graphType", "").equals("m"))

    {

        int index = 0;

        String[] dates = new String[totalOrdersList.size()];


        mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);

        mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

        mChart.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.lightGrey));

        //   mChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        // if more than 60 entries are displayed in the chart, no values will be
        // drawn
        mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);

        // scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
        mChart.setPinchZoom(false);

        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        // mChart.setDrawYLabels(false);

        IndexAxisValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new IndexAxisValueFormatter(dates);

        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setLabelCount(3);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IAxisValueFormatter custom = new MyAxisValueFormatter();


        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setLabelCount(8, false);
        leftAxis.setValueFormatter(custom);
        leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
        leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

        YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        rightAxis.setLabelCount(8, false);
        rightAxis.setValueFormatter(custom);
        rightAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
        rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
        rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
        // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
        l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
        l.setDrawInside(false);
        l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE);
        l.setFormSize(9f);
        l.setTextSize(11f);
        l.setXEntrySpace(4f);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();


        for (Order o : totalOrdersList) {

            dates[index] = o.getDate();
            barEntries.add(new BarEntry(index, Float.parseFloat(o.getAmount())));

            index++;
        }


        BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Months");
        set1.setValues(barEntries);


        set1.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.orange));

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);

        data.setValueTextSize(10f);
        data.setBarWidth(0.9f);

        mChart.setData(data);

        mChart.animateXY(3000, 3000);

    }
```

Please help.. Thank you..